# How to input First Order Non Linear ODE that are dependent on each other into Runge-Kutta

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, nonlinear-analysis, runge-kutta-methods

I am working on ODE's that are highly non linear (even at only their first order expressions). The governing equations of motion describes a complex phenomenon of bubbles underwater. Runge Kutta 4 methodology was suggested by a colleague in solving the system of ODE's. I'm having trouble experessing them into RK4 format such that

$$y'=f(x)$$

I have sampled a simple similar problem below to describe the complex nonlinearity. Suppose that I have this system of Linear ODE'S (derivatives with respect to  $t$ )

$$x' + y'= 3xy + x'y'- 4t$$

$$y'=y^2 - xt - (x')^2$$

with Initial Conditions $x(0)=x_0$ and $y(0)=y_0$.

How can I input these 2 equations into Runge-Kutta 4th Order. I know how to treat second order ODE, by converting into first order for Runge-Kutta formulation but I don't know how to resolve the above first order ODEs for multivariable.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do $x'$ and $y'$ denote the time derivatives (with respect to $t$)? What is $z^2$ in the second equation?

Comment: Sincerely apologize for the confusion, Yes. the derivatives on x and y are with respect to time, but the z^2 is a typo, needs to be replaced by y^2. Thank you very much for catching this typing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat the equation as a DAE system, differential-algebraic equations, and use and DAE solver. This means to introduce an additional state variable $v=y'$, which is then also the new second differential equation, and transform the difference of the equations into an algebraic, which means here derivative-free, equation.

A second variant is to take the derivative of both equations and solve the resulting system of second-order DE.

In this special case the difference of both equations is quadratic in $y'$, which can be solved by the usual formula. However, one has to take care of the double-root case where the solution may cease to exist, or branches cross over, possibly generating a discontinuity in the second derivative.

---

Specific to get a system for RK4: Solve the linear system
$$
u+v-uv=3xy-4t\\
u^2+v=y^2-xt
$$
for $u$ and $v$ for given $t_0,x_0,y_0$, select one of the 4 solutions.

Apply RK4 in the vector version. Manually or via a solver routine solve in the ODE function the system
$$
\pmatrix{1-v& 1-u\\2u&1}\pmatrix{u'\\v'}
=
\pmatrix{3uy+3xv-4\\2yv-ut-x}
$$
input $[x,y,u,v]$, output $[u,v,u',v']$. Check for sign changes in the determinant, avoid division by zero.

Comment: Good day Dr. Lehmann, I apologize that I had a typo in my question above. There is no "dependent variable "z" that has no derivative". Do, I still need to employ DAE?  The variables are x and y and their derivatives are with respect to time, t. Is there a way to formulate this into using Runge-Kutta? Thank you sir

Comment: In this case the solution via quadratic equation falls away. The reduction to second order in both equations (and getting the initial condition by solving the original system as algebraic system for the first derivatives) still remains compatible with RK4. The usual drift via method truncation error and floating-point noise will occur but can be reduced via projection.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Lehmann. I'm going to implement this solution on Matlab and I will update how everything turns out. Very very much appreciated sir.

Comment: You might want to try out the Julia library DifferentialEquations.jl for this.

Comment: Good day Lehmann! As I'm coding this problem in Matlab, I'm stumbled upon one issue. You have mentioned that, the output vector will be [u, v, u', v'] and input vector [x, y, u, v] but this a 2-equation ODE system of Ax'=b. Meaning my function header is derivs(t,z) where z is u' and v'. which also means that, in a RK4, the corresponding k-values will be  k1 = h*f(t,z) ,   k2 = h*f(t+0.5*h,x+0.5*k1)... etc. How do input the reminder variables [x, y] to get updated for k-values ? Thank you sir